# Split long XML tags in multiple lines with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml, pretty-print

My python (2.7) script is outputting the following XML using `lxml` library:

```xml
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="17dp" android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:text="Button"/>
```

I would like to output it in multiple lines, one per attribute:

```xml
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
  android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: You'd have to locate the documentation for the transformer serializer implementation used by lxml and determine if it has any parameters that would allow control over this.  I highly doubt it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JimGarrison. I looked up in the lxml docs and I could not find any information about this. I can easily manipulate strings after tags, but I have no control with strings after attributes. I also looked up in the source code in order to check if I could customize the `method` parameter in the `write()` function but I got nothing from it.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a very naive and inefficient approach.

After generating the xml using `lxml` library, I process the output.
The following code is only tested to work with `lxml` output and assumes we have a tag per line.

```js
output = etree.tostring(
    tree,
    xml_declaration=True,
    pretty_print=True,
    encoding=tree.docinfo.encoding,
)
output = output.replace("\" ","\"\n")
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    parent_tag_line = None
    for i, line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
        line_stripped = line.lstrip(" ")
        line_ident = len(line) - len(line_stripped)
        if parent_tag_line is not None:
            if line_ident == 0 and line[:2] != "</":
                line = (parent_line_ident+2)*" " + line
            else:
                parent_tag_line = line
                parent_line_ident = line_ident
                line_stripped = line.lstrip()
                if line_stripped[:4] != "<!--" and line_stripped[:2] != "</":
                    line="\n"+line
        else:
            parent_tag_line = line
            parent_line_ident = line_ident
        print >>f, line
```

Although this gets the job done, it is far from being an optimal approach.
I wonder if there's a better and simpler way of doing this.